# how to activate adjustsize() for a layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

i'm programming in QT. I encountered a problem. i would

like to activate adjustsize() for a layout from the cpp

file. i can't find the function, which exist on the designer.

designer screenshot:

[image]

cpp:ui->gridLayout->no matched function!!!

Comment: I am also learnng and I am not sure but I think you should do `x->setSize(x->sizeHint())`

Answer (score 3):

That maps to [QWidget::adjustSize()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#adjustSize).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it on the widget that is using the layout: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#adjustSize